# Pip says old version is installed after installing new version

Tags: python, pip, version

I uninstalled pip and reinstalled it from `get-pip.py`, yet it reports the wrong version.

```
C:\>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1

C:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
PS C:\> pip --version
pip 6.0.3 from c:\python33\lib (python 3.3)
```

Has the correct version been installed? Every time I use pip it still tells me to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `c:\python33\lib\pip` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a clue for my own problem where pip had upgraded from 8.1.0 to 8.1.1 but it was stuck thinking it still needed to upgrade and it couldn't remove 8.1.0.  Deleting the old 8.1.0 directory enabled it to properly recognize it was already updated to 8.1.1.