# Tensorflow: Uninstall CPU version getting Fatal Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pip, installation-package

I installed CPU version in windows 10 and want to completely uninstall it. while using pip getting the 'Fatal error in launcher:'

My Command: `pip uninstall tensorflow`

Error I am getting:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""c:\users\hasan mosharrof\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe" 
 "C:\Users\Hasan Mosharrof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe" uninstall tensorflow'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you'll get a much better response if you copy the error message into your question in the form of text formatted as code. External links are generally bad form (hard for potential answerers to read, and hard to search for later). Also, this appears to be a `pip` issue so I've updated your tags to reflect that.

Comment: This may be a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144949/pip-says-old-version-is-installed-after-installing-new-version?rq=1

Comment: You can edit your question and format it nicely. I don't know the answer myself, I was only suggesting that a well formatted question is more likely to get a response.

Comment: @DavidParks: Thanks